# html2canvas and jsPDF in angular5 low quality

Tags: javascript, html, angular5, jspdf, html2canvas

This is my code in component and I tried many things.

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('content'),{scale: 1}).then(function(canvas){
    var image=canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    canvas.getContext('2d').mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    canvas.getContext('2d').imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
    var doc=new jsPDF();
    doc.addImage(image,"PNG",0,0);
    doc.save("test.pdf");
});
```

This is the output I'm getting. How can I improve the quality?

[image: this is what i get]

Comment: What is actually going wrong?

Comment: Your rendering to a raster format (png), based on a screen scaling, normally about 72ppi, printed material is usually at least 300ppi.  You could maybe scale up your html2canvas to say `{scale:4}` and then shrink the image on the pdf.